# Zend Route incorrect relative path

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

My routes work fine apart from when I am at an action that requires a parameter. For example, these work ok:

```
/news
/news/admin
/news/admin/add
```

But this doesn't:

```
/news/admin/edit/1
```

But only routes using the 'default' route render incorrectly (they render as ../../module/controller), all other routes render correctly (/module/conntroller)

Any ideas why, or how to fix it?

Comment: - Did you define any custom routes? 
- Try /news/admin/edit/id/1 (mind the parameter name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a common problem.

If you are using custom routes in your navigation you must explicitly pass 'default' route to Zend_Navigation pages and url() view helpers.

Also your page parameters must match parameters defined in Zend_Navigation

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using custom routes, your route has to look like this:

```
/news/admin/edit/id/1
```

Where there always have to be a pair of /param/value.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that I have a custom route defined