# Zend Naviation Menu View Helper - All links are the same?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation

heres my setup:

```
http://www.example.com/<module>/<controller>/<action>
```

I have this route defined:

```
$router->addRoute(
            'editUser', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('admin/users/edit/:id',
                array(
                    'module'     => 'admin',
                    'controller' => 'users',
                    'action'     => 'edit',
                    'route'      => 'default',
                    'id'         => 0,
                ),
                array('id' => '\d+')
            )
        );
```

So my sites navigation menu works fine until i go to a page like so:

```
http://www.example.com/admin/users/edit/10
```

It displays the page no problem but now every link in the navigation menu points to `http://www.example.com/admin/users/edit`

Not sure why this is happening and would like to get it fixed while maintaining use of the router.

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Comment: Can you post your navigation code?

Comment: I had the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530448/zend-route-ncorrect-relative-path, but unfortunately i haven't found an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a common problem.

If you are using custom routes in your navigation (editUser in your case) you must explicitly pass 'default' route to Zend_Navigation pages and url() view helpers.